# Static bindings in PHP

Tags: php, static

The following code is [Example #4 from the PHP documentation on late static bindings](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#example-240).

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function foo() {
        static::who();
    }

    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function test() {
        A::foo();
        parent::foo();
        self::foo();
    }

    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}
class C extends B {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__."\n";
    }
}

C::test();
```

My question is why the output is "ACC" but not "ABC". Expecting your helps!

Comment: The functions are executing in the scope of C via self and parent, so __CLASS__ is returning C

Comment: The documentation (from which you copied without attribution) explains the difference between forwarding and non-forwarding calls and gives this code as an example of how that works. If you want help, please explain why the documentation that contains this example and an explanation of the example does not address your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have less knowledges about "non-forwarding call".Access to the [link](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) and find what you need.

Comment: It's better to include the full explanation of your answer rather than simply point to a link (that may disappear in time). It's not clear what you are offering as the answer.